# Reverse z Score pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, normalization

I am using this to compute the z score of my dataframe:

```
df_z=df.apply(zscore)
```

Is there a reverse operation that can give me the orginal values?

Comment: Or would it be possible to this by hand?

Comment: sklearn minmaxscaler has an option like this:  inverse_transform(X). Would there be a similar function for z score?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in way to go from df_z (z scores) back to df (original values). However, you can do it fairly easily as follows:

Step 1: Keep track of the mean and standard deviations of all of the original variables.
Perhaps like this:

```py
mean_std={}
for var in df.columns:
    mean_std[var]=(df[var].mean(), df[var].std())
```

Step 2: Convert back to z scores

```py
def reverse_zscore(pandas_series, mean, std):
    '''Mean and standard deviation should be of original variable before standardization'''
    yis=pandas_series*std+mean
    return yis

original_mean, original_std = mean_std[var]
original_var_series = reverse_zscore(df_z[var], original_mean, original_std)
```

Alternatively, just store your original dataframe somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You can use StandardScaler from SciKit Learn which basically will do the above logic for you.
As the name does not indicate StandardScaler is Z Scoring class.

so

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

zscore = StandardScaler()

# Do the scoring
out = zscore.fit_transform(x)

# Do the reverse
x = zscore.inverse_transform(out)
```